# What can I do to make my PHP web application fail in a more noisy way?

Tags: php

What can I do to make my PHP web application fail in a more noisy way?

I am using an MVC pattern and often when classes fail to load or failures they do so without error.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );
ini_set( 'log_errors', '1' );

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  system('/usr/bin/mplayer /home/user/music/Moras_Modern_Rhythmists/Mr._Ghost_Goes_to_Town.mp3', $retval);
  return true;
}

set_error_handler( "error_handler" );
?>
```

Comment: Pretty cool.  Imagine doing this on a colocated server (yes, I know they're not likely to have sound cards).

Comment: If you have display_errors off in php.ini, you will not see errors outputted to the browser that prevent your script from executing, such as parse errors.

Comment: error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );
ini_set( 'log_errors', '1' );

This was what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your error reporting level is at, you could try raising it via .htaccess.

```
php_value display_errors 1
php_value error_reporting 2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the require_once method to load your files instead of include.

I think that's what you're asking, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing testing, check whether your php.ini settings has display_errors property turned on.

Comment: Also, please note that I mentioned "testing" because this setting should almost always be turned off in production as this might compromise security.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?  ini_set("Melodramatic", "true"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer: `die('A fatal error occurred')`

In a PHP application I wrote, I came up with a convention of using a variable or class member named `$err_msg` which is initially set to null .  When an error happens, set it to a human readable string.  When it's time to check errors, check `$err_msg` and put it on display for the end-user.  If it's an AJAX call, `echo $err_msg` on failure, `echo 'OK'` on success.

In my case, I wrote a simple jQuery-based status box that can display busy indicators and errors.  When an AJAX call returns an error message, I make the status box fade in with a red background and display the error message.  It's quite nice and uniform.

Comment: I use die() in places to help, but not everywhere.

This helped me. It E_ALL generates more errors than E_STRICT.
error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' ); ini_set( 'log_errors', '1' ); 

 Thank you.